# What's the general purpose of a sandbox for a browser? Does it clean viruses along with something else, or is it just used to clean virus attempts?

Tags: windows-7

I feel like this would be relevant in a situation as so, but maybe they have a different purpose. I tried using a Chromebook for some dangerous spam, but it just wiped before i could even look at the message.
I feel like if a person Phished you, they could could also encrypt a virus to all your banking on a computer to drain money.

Comment: Did you try to find out?

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of a sandbox is to limit the resources the program can access.

This has a side effect of limiting the amount of damage Virii can do (it does not clean virii, but it could stop them from spreading in some cases)

Sandboxes also have other uses, for example they can limit the amount of resources available to the window/program - which means that if configured appropriately, a program which wants to hog all the available resources can't do it.   It also means that if someone/something gets access to the program which shouldn't, it can't escallate its privileges past what the sandbox allows to do more money.

From a practical POV a sandbox will not always prevent phishing attacks, but they could stop an attacker getting information from other open windows, and could limit the damage the spam could do.    [In a browser with sandoxing] If you enter your banking credentials into the same browser/window as the phishing email the attacker can still get your details and empty out your bank account, but they will find it much harder to access other files or windows on your system, so they may not be able to hijack another window where you are doing banking for example.